# How can I refer to a parent from a child?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, instances

The wording of the title probably needs re-visiting, but for now consider the following code:

```
var ParentControl = function()
{
    this.ShowAlert = function()
    {
        alert('hi!');
    }

    this.childControl = new ChildControl();
};

var ChildControl = function()
{
    // IN THIS SCOPE HERE I NEED TO CALL 'ShowAlert'
};

var parentControl = new ParentControl();
```

As per the comment in the code snippet above, I need instances of `ChildControl` to call the 'ShowAlert' function of their parent but I don't know how.

**What I've Tried**

Simply calling `ParentControl.ShowAlert()` where I've wrote the comment - obviously doesn't work as `parentControl` is the instance (I don't want to refer to this explicitly).

I've also tried passing in the parent control to the constructor of `ChildControl` but I ideally wanted to keep the child control independent from any particular type of parent.

Comment: *"I ideally wanted to keep the child control independent from any particular type of parent"* In that case, how about some kind of event publisher/subscribe pattern? The `ChildControl` instance emits an event/message and the `ParentControl` instance reacts to it.

Comment: @FelixKling - this sounds ideal. I know I could expose this event as `this.somethingHappened` on the child but how could the parent know that something happened? Or is my approach wrong?

Comment: I'm not very good at reading, and still don't understand what the issue with just passing `new ChildControl(this);` inside the parent is ?

Comment: or this -> http://jsfiddle.net/mQMUc/ ?

Comment: Inside the child, you do `this.emit('foo')` and the parent has to listen to the child with `this.childControl.subscribe('foo', callback)`. In your case it seems that the event would be emitted before the parent subscribes, in which case you also have to implement a mechanism that "replays" emitted events to new subscribers. **However** passing the parent as dependency to the child is a much simpler solution, and you should go with that if there are no major reasons against it. Keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also move showAlert onto the prototype, so you're not creating a new function in memory every time you instantiate ParentControl.

```
var ParentControl = function() {
    this.childControl = new ChildControl(this);
};

ParentControl.prototype.showAlert = function() {
  console.log('hello');
};

var ChildControl = function(parent) {
  parent.showAlert();
};

var parentControl = new ParentControl();
```

Comment: So, the OP is saying *"I've also tried passing in the parent control to the constructor of ChildControl but, I ideally wanted to keep the child control independent from any particular type of parent."*, and your answer is *"just pass the parent to the child"*? It seems like you focused on a technicality (the prototype) instead of the actual question.